# iOS Facebook Authorize failing if Facebook app is installed

Tags: ios, facebook

Facebook SSO authentication is working just fine in my iOS app when using Safari, but if I have the Facebook app installed SSO redirects over to it instead and the authorization hangs. It's not failing like many other people on SO are talking about, I'm getting an empty dialog box that just says "Loading..." It hangs forever and eventually crashes.

I can force my app to always use Safari authentication, but I'd like to know if there is a way to get the FB app working before I resort to that.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same behavior and the appDelegate method was implemented.

By looking at the URL received by this method I've realized my bundle ID was different on the app config at the Facebook page:
"fb41810xxxxxx://authorize#error_description=Invalid%2BIOS%2Bbundle%2BID&error=unknown%5Ferror"

I've corrected the setting and everything worked fine.

Comment: My BundleID on facebook app settings was correct, but i just rewrite this field and save. It solved my prolem with Invalid%2BIOS%2Bbundle%2BID

Answer (score -1):

Ensure your appdelegate is implementing the method application:openURL, like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[[FacebookController sharedInstance] facebook ]handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```

Comment: I did have that set up, it's not a problem of redirecting back to my app properly, it was a problem on the Facebook side. It couldn't load the initial Facebook page.